# django test - how to get response data for future use

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm running a login test like so:

```
def test_login_user(self):
    client = APIClient()
    url = reverse('rest_login')
    data = {
        'username': 'test',
        'password': 'Welcome2'
    }
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    client.logout()
```

If I login to the app normally I see a json return like this:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImV2YW4iLCJleHAiOjE1MTQ2NzYzNTYsImVtYWlsIjoiZXZhbkAyOGJlYXR0eS5jb20iLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTUxNDY3Mjc1Nn0.8CfhfgtMLkNjEaWBfNXbUWXQMZG4_LIru_y4pdLlmeI",
    "user": {
        "pk": 2,
        "username": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    }
}
```

I want to be able to grab that `token` value for future use however the `response` does not seem to have a `data` value to grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show error response:

```
response.context["form"].errors
```

Answer (score 13):

What I'm looking for is `response.content` per the official documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses

Answer (score 1):

You can use response.json()['token'] to get data from the token field.

Usage as below:

token = response.json()['token'];

Comment: Please try to add some supporting information to your post that explains what your code does. There appears to be issues with formatting in your answer as well, take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow